# Is there a way to "embed" a form in another form

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I have a form and I want to embed it in another form. I want to keep both form, but I would prefer to avoid duplicating the first form.

Is there a way to "attach" a form to a tab page for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

Use field groups on the tables to the max and accept the fact.

Or provide a button to the second form.